# Verify a file signature inside a Linux kernel module

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, cryptography, public-key-encryption

When I want to verify if a given file has been signed by the public keys private counterpart, I would use openssl like this:

```
openssl dgst -verify public.pem -signature file.sha1 file.data
```

How can I accomplish this inside a Linux 3 kernel module?

Comment: Why would you want the kernel to do it when a userspace program does it fine? Are you trying to verify executable or kernel module signatures upon loading?

Comment: For some kind of License verification mechanism.
If the verification fails parts of the system need to be disabled.
I thought about compiling this into the kernel to make tempering more difficult.

Comment: Hmmm, I'd tread very carefully if you're going to head into kernel space (I wouldn't recommend it). It's certainly possible to write a module to do it but could easily compromise the stability of the system if it isn't written properly.

Comment: You cant do it from your application, your kernel / module would generally be signed by the vendors private key, while loading the module if you have vendors pub-key installed in the correct location this should load a properly signed module, if not give an error `An attempt to load unsigned module was rejected`. Google for secure Linux kernel modules and should get several hits.